# Can't find module hooker when run grunt jshint

Tags: gruntjs, runtime-error, grunt-contrib-jshint

When I run `grunt jshint` in cmd, show me below error:

```
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
Error: Cannot find module 'hooker
Warning: Task "jshint:myFiles" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.`
```

this is my code:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({

// define source files and their destinations
uglify: {
   min: {
        files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['vendors/**/**/*.js','!vendors/**/**/*.min.js'], '', {
            rename: function(destBase, destPath) {
                return destBase+destPath.replace('.js', '.min.js');
            }
        })
    }
},
watch: {
    files:['vendors/**/**/*.min.js'],
    tasks: ['default']
},
clean: ["vendors"],
bower: {
    install: {
       //just run 'grunt bower:install' and you'll see files from your Bower packages in lib directory 
    }
},
jshint: {
  // You get to make the name
  // The paths tell JSHint which files to validate
  myFiles: ['gruntfile.js']
},
cssmin:{
    target: {
        files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['vendors/**/**/*.css','!vendors/**/**/*.min.css'], '', {
            rename: function(destBase, destPath) {
                return destBase+destPath.replace('.css', '.min.css','');
            }
        })
    }
},
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-installer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-watch-github');

// register at least this one task
grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'jshint','uglify','cssmin' ]);


};
```

I Installed these plugins:

> {
>     "name": "my-project-name",
>     "version": "1.0.0",
>     "devDependencies": {
>       "grunt": "~0.4.2",
>       "grunt-bower-installer": "^0.3.6",
>       "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.3",
>       "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.14.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.4",
>       "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.3",
>       "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.4",
>       "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
>       "grunt-watch-github": "^0.1.1",
>       "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1"
>     }
>   }

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem with install jshint module again. Because jshint doesn't install correctly

```
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
```